# Android Progress Bar Animation

Tags: android, animation, progress-bar, android-animation, android-progressbar

I'm trying to create a progress bar that will fill up from LEFT to RIGHT then once its full empty from LEFT to RIGHT. It animated well only once. Then is fill up from the RIGHT to LEFT and and empty LEFT to RIGHT.

What it should be:
http://i.imgur.com/ZuAsngc.gif?1

What it is doing right now:
http://i.imgur.com/69qixqO.gifv

We can see in the gif it does it well the first time. Then it messes up. I dont know if its related to the **interpolatedTime**

```
ProgressBarAnimation anim = new ProgressBarAnimation(progressBar, 0,100);
        anim.setDuration(1000);
        anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
        progressBar.startAnimation(anim);
```

Progress Class

```
class ProgressBarAnimation extends Animation{
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private float from;
    private float  to;
    private boolean isForward;
    private float value;

    public ProgressBarAnimation(ProgressBar progressBar, float from, float to) {
        super();
        this.progressBar = progressBar;
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
        isForward = true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
        super.applyTransformation(interpolatedTime, t);
        if(isForward) {
            value = from + (to - from) * interpolatedTime;
            progressBar.setProgress((int) value);
            if(value == 100){
                isForward = false;
                progressBar.setRotation(180);
                value = 0;
            }
        }
        else{
            value = to + (from - to) * interpolatedTime;
            progressBar.setProgress((int) value);
            if(value2 == 0){
                isForward = true;
                progressBar.setRotation(180);
                value = 100;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try debugging if it ever reaches the `isForward = true;` line to switch back?

Comment: Yes it does, Also you can see in the gif it does it well the first time. Then it messes up. I dont know if its related to the interpolatedTime

Comment: It might be the rotation then. You set it to 180° in both cases. the second one should be 0°, shouldnt it?

Comment: Omg! Thanks man it works!!!